# Python / Tkinker application with multiple files / imports

Tags: python, tkinter, import, module

Working on a Tkinter GUI application. Since the code is becoming fairly large, I would like to start splitting it up into different files. Eg. Separate file for classes, separate file for functions etc.

However, if we take the class.py file, this contains several classes based on e.g. Tkinter widgets.
code snippet:

```
class MylabelFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent,labels,header):
        super().__init__()
        self.labels=labels
        self.configure(text=header)
        self.parent=parent
        thisRow=0
        thisColumn=0
        self.textvar='n/a'
        for i in self.labels:
          <and so on>
```

so the structure could look like:

```
/main
   main.py                   (need to import Tkinter tk)
   /lib
      class.py               (need to import Tkinter tk)
      functions.py           (need to import Tkinter tk)
```

When debugging the app, it throws an error, since e.g. class.py cannot build because of the lack of importing tk. However, the import is done in the main, but this is not excepted.

```
NameError: name 'tk' is not defined
```

I understand we have the **init.py** and **all**, but this does not solve the issue here in my view..

What is the proper way of dealing with this? Ofcourse I can use the same imports for every file, but this feels like creating overhead? In the end I will need to import the same modules on every .py file... There must be a smarter way of doing this I assume?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would just go ahead and import tkinter in every module you need it. That is simple and clear and doesn't cost the overhead you fear it does - you will only be creating references to the already-loaded module from the first time it was imported

Answer (score 1):

All files must import from tkinter to know what "tk" means.
A better approach would be to create an import file, like so:

Create a file called tk_imports.py:

```
import tkinter as tk    # Python3
```

Then all `main.py`, `class.py` and `functions.py` may import from it:

```
from tk_imports import *
```

You can use a **wildcard import** here because all you're doing is importing "tkinter as tk" with additional steps. You'll still need to put `tk.` before you call a tkinter class in your code. This way your files won't repeat themselves by importing tkinter thrice.